# How do I determine I am down in the last folder of the given directory tree in Python?

Tags: python, file-io, filesystems

I would like to parse a given directory tree all the way  down and stop at the last folder and check for existing of certain files (say .nfo file) just in that last folder.

The directory tree and its sub folders might contain some files, so checking to see if the folder has files as a solution is a no go for me.

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked into `os.path.walk`? Please provide us with your attempt and expected output so that we can better help you.

Comment: It tried pathlib.Path().rglob

Comment: Please show us your full minimal, complete and verified code in your post. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I would do is:
iterate through the directories recursively. Have a counter for the level of depth that you are in. Every time you find a new directory, that has a depth >= your current counter. save the new path and set the counter (for >).
By that you have to run over all subdirectories once and at the end you have the path to the last folder.
Then do the check for the file in that path.

Try this:

```
path = 'To:\\Be\\Set'
counter = 0

def getFile(path, counter, result):
    counterTmp = counter
    list = os.listdir(path)
    print (path)
    #print (list)
    for item in list:
        if (os.path.isdir(path +"\\"+ item)):
            if (len(os.listdir(path +"\\"+ item)) > 0):
                result, counter = getFile(path+"\\"+item, counterTmp + 1, result)
        elif (counterTmp >= counter):
            result = path
    return result, counterTmp

def checkFiles(path, setToCheck):
    list = os.listDir(path)
    result = []
    for file in list:
        if (file in setToCheck)
            result.append(file)
    return result

path, counter = getFile(path, 0, '')
println(path)
setToCheck = set(["toBeFilled"])
println(checkFiles(path, setToCheck))
```

Comment: Yes but there are many directories with subfolders under the given directory. It seems to me that the dept counter you talk is to assume that there is a single directory inside the given directory?

Comment: no, because you run over all subdirectories in a recursive manner, it will go deep into the first, then go back up and access the 2nd, go deep again, aso.
Until you reach the last one. So it will return you the last folder with maximum depth.

Comment: ok thanks, I will see how I can implement this, although I have no idea about it now

Comment: I added a solution up there. Have a look.

Comment: thank you, I will give it a go and give feedback if I have any. cheers